# Using smartctl to get vendor specific Attributes from ssd drive behind a SmartArray P410 controller

Tags: ssd, hp-smart-array

Recently I have deployed some HP server with SSD's behind a SmartArray P410 controller. While not official supported from HP the server work well sofar.

Now I like to get wear level info's, error statistics etc from the drive. While the SA P410 supports a passthru of the SMART Command to a single drive in the array the output I was not able to the the interesting things from the drive.

In this case especially the value the Wear level indicator is from interest for me (Attr.ID 233), but this is ony present if the drive is directly attanched to a SATA Controller.

**smartctl on directly connected ssd:**

```
# smartctl -A /dev/sda
smartctl version 5.38 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8
Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 5
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE     
UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0000   100   000   000    Old_age  Offline  In_the_past 0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0000   100   000   000    Old_age  Offline  In_the_past 0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age  Always       -       8561
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age  Always       -       55
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age  Always       -       29
232 Unknown_Attribute       0x0003   100   100   010    Pre-fail Always       -       0
233 Unknown_Attribute       0x0002   088   088   000    Old_age  Always       -       0
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0000   198   198   000    Old_age  Offline      -      508509
226 Load-in_Time            0x0002   255   000   000    Old_age  Always   In_the_past 0
227 Torq-amp_Count          0x0002   000   000   000    Old_age  Always   FAILING_NOW 0
228 Power-off_Retract_Count 0x0002   000   000   000    Old_age  Always   FAILING_NOW 0
```

**smartctl on P410 connected ssd:**

```
# ./smartctl -A -d cciss,0 /dev/cciss/c1d0
smartctl 5.39.1 2010-01-28 r3054 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
```

(Right, it is complety empty)

**smartctl on P410 connected hdd:**

```
# ./smartctl -A -d cciss,0 /dev/cciss/c0d0
smartctl 5.39.1 2010-01-28 r3054 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Current Drive Temperature:     27 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C
Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 1871654030
  Blocks received from initiator = 1360012929
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 2178203797
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 46052239
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0
Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 3363.25
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 12
```

Do I hunt here a bug, or is this a limitation of the p410 SMART cmd Passthru?

Comment: Can you return the output of "cat /proc/scsi/scsi"

Comment: the cciss driver does not implement a scsi host adapter therefore the /proc/scsi/scsi is empty.

Comment: Oh, the hpsa module exposes the controller as a scsi device. I assume then your using the older cciss module?

Comment: Yes, the server are running under a 2.6.32 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a limitation of the p410 because it doesn't support SSD.

Comment: With controller firmware updates, some info is passed through. HP has a wear indicator for SSDs with HP firmware now.

Answer (score 2):

Recent OS versions use hpsa driver instead of cciss. So this command might work if you don't have /dev/cciss/* devices:

smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/sg0

Answer (score 1):

I have tested 
smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/sg0

and it works on HP SSDs, but fail on Samsung SM1625 SSDs.

I believe the drives needs the HP firmware to pass information to the host.